# Notepad strange characters

Tags: notepad

I’m trying to edit a steam game save file but when i go through steam and open the save file it’s full of weird characters and none of it is making sense. I’ve downloaded notepad ++ and it’s the same in there. All the game save files are the same. Is it because I have wemod or plitch in the game. [photo of notepad][1]

Can anyone help me to fix it or decrypt it? I’m running windows 10.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8bxB.jpg)

Comment: That looks like you are opening a binary files with a text editor.

Comment: There's *probably* nothing to decrypt. The file stores binary information, it most likely has some internal structure (probably specific to the game). One may say the information is encoded [but not encrypted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4657517/10765659). Tools may exist to open and modify save files of this specific game; and/or there may be some hints about what bytes to change (in a [binary editor](https://superuser.com/q/1055977/432690)) to increase your in-game money or whatever.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yeah I think the developers have made it so people can’t mod the same.. boring 